# Posicion del numero primo mayor en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas tardes este es mi codigo llevo casi 2 horas mirando en que me estoy equivocando y no he podido saber por favor me podrian ayudar

'''Leer 10 enteros, almacenarlos en una lista y determinar en qué posición de la lista está el mayor número primo leído'''

try:

```
lista=[]
pos=0

for i in range(10):
    numero=int(input("Digite un numero entero: "))
    lista.append(numero)

mayor=lista[0]
aumento=0

for l in range(len(lista)): 
    if (lista[l]%l)==0:
        aumento+=1

    if aumento==2:
        if lista [l] > mayor:
            lista[l] = mayor
            pos=l+1

print("El numero primo mayor se encuentra en la posicion %d"%pos)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo detectas si un numero es o no primo? Deberías resolver primero este algoritmos, el codicional `if (lista[l]%l)==0:` es siempre cierto (todo entero es divisible entre si mismo), aparte, `l`  es el índice no el número...

Comment: No veo que estés comprobando si los elementos de la lista son primos o no. Tampoco entiendo la lógica de incrementar `aumento` cuando `lista[l]%l==0` ¿Qué tiene que ver si el número es divisible o no por el índice que ocupa dentro de la lista? ¿Qué pasa además si `aumento` vale 3 o más? Creo que no se puede señalar un error concreto, sino que todo el algoritmo está mal pensado.

Comment: Yo creo que por ahora sólo está recorriendo el arreglo e imprimiendo el número mayor en la lista. Cuando eso le resulte, comprobará si es primo.

Comment: De hecho, amenadiel, eso no es lo que está buscando él. Claramente dice el mayor número primo, no si el número mayor ingresado es primo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es donde le asignas el valor a "mayor"

```
 mayor=lista[0]
```

Le asignas a mayor el primer número almacenado en tu arreglo lista[], por lo tanto el primer número almacenado siempre será el que estás comparando

Answer (score 0):

Bien, primeramente no sé qué quisiste hacer acá:

```
if (lista[l]%l)==0:
    aumento+=1
```

Y acá:

```
if aumento==2:
    if lista [l] > mayor:
        lista[l] = mayor
        pos=l+1
```

Lo tienes al revés! Te explico por qué: Si el número en la posición x es mayor al que está guardado en la variable 'mayor', entonces, tienes que almacenar ese número de la posición x en 'mayor' y no igualar el elemento de la lista al valor de 'mayor' porque esto borraría al numero que es mayor al que está en 'mayor' (que lío jaja)

En resumen, sería esto:

```
if aumento==2:
    if lista [l] > mayor:
        # Puesto que lista[l] es mayor a 'mayor'
        # Tomo el elemento lista[l] como mi nuevo 'mayor'
        mayor = lista[l] 
        pos=l+1
```

Si en la parte de arriba, buscaste comprobar si un número es primo o no, te recomiendo que hagas algo así dentro del for:

```
for k in range(1,(lista[l]+1)): # Compruebo desde 1 hasta el numero 
    if(lista[l]%k==0):          # Por cuanto de los numeros es divisible
        aumento+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que por ahora te estás saltando la problemática de saber si el número es primo o no, y estás en la parte de determinar el máximo número de la lista.

En ese caso debiera ser:

```
mayor=0
pos=0

for l in range(len(lista)): 
    if lista [l] > mayor:
       mayor = lista[l]
       pos=l+1

print("El numero primo mayor se encuentra en la posicion %d"%pos)
```

Puse al pricipio que el mayor es cero y está en la posición cero, porque así trato todas las iteraciones igual sin importar si son la primera o las otras 9.

Pero te sigue quedando pendiente resolver lo otro, y no es trivial. (Aunque es muy googleable)